# Modify excerpt link

Tags: excerpt

I read the thread about adding a filter on the last line of the code, but am not sure that will work here.

http://www.ahy4life.com/resources.php

In the middle right column in the Promotions section, the 'Continue reading ->' link is linked to the wrong page.

How can I correct this?

```
<div id="globalcontent">
  <?php
  $featuredPosts = new WP_Query();
  $featuredPosts->query('showposts=5&cat=8');
  while ($featuredPosts->have_posts()) : $featuredPosts->the_post(); ?>
    <h2 style="color:#FFFFFF; background:url(http://ahy4life.com/images/right_top_header.jpg) no-repeat left top;"><center><?php the_title(); ?></center></h2>
    <div>
      <style type="text/css">
      div a{
       color:#FFFFFF;
      }
      </style>

      <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<div><img src="images/right_top_footer.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div style="background-color: #FFF;"></div>
```

TIA

Comment: If you mean "middle ***of the*** right column on the Promotions page", that section is talking about events and the link is to the events page. What is the problem?

Comment: @user24732 Both box's ("events" and "promotion") continue reading link pointing to same events.php. Is it what you are trying to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Use "[wp_reset_postdata();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)" right after "endwhile;" seems like your second query fetching link from your previous query.